# Top 10 users for each game in neo4j based of games they like for each category

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to get top 10 users who have liked particular game with game_id from 1 to 25. These games have a relationship with user called rating with property rating_val=1 to 10 .

How to get 25 rows with group of all users who have rating_val from 1 to 10 desc order for each game category.

Basically :
25 game categories with id 1 to 25 games_like is a relationship with with rating_val from 1-10 users are nodes with id,name

This query is not working I guess my approach and implementation are both wrong:

```
MATCH (u:user { user_id:"1" })
MATCH (o:user)
WHERE o <> u 
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[r:games_like]->(d)<-[rw:games_like]-(o)
RETURN
  toInt(r.rating_val)+toInt(rw.rating_val) as sum ,
  collect(DISTINCT (r.rating_val)) AS user1,
  collect(DISTINCT (rw.rating_val)) AS user2,
  d
ORDER BY sum DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can create a dataset and share what you expect?

Except the global match for (o:user) it doesn't look incorrect.

You group by sum and game (prob remove the game) ?? 
And how do categories that you mention come in?

Try this, simplified the match and removed the grouping by game only by sum of ratings.

```
MATCH (u:user { user_id:"1" })-[r:games_like]->()<-[rw:games_like]-(o:user)
WHERE o <> u 
RETURN
  toInt(r.rating_val)+toInt(rw.rating_val) as sum ,
  collect(DISTINCT (r.rating_val)) AS user1,
  collect(DISTINCT (rw.rating_val)) AS user2
ORDER BY sum DESC
LIMIT 25
```

Comment: But I would like to get all other user's id along with the name of the game they have liked.Currently I am getting only the ratings as 2 columns row1 and row2 but I am not looking for that also my query above is wrong(Sorry).Please let me know where I can post the data set .Thanks